# react functional component not get initialised

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have logout component(stateless) in that I want to delete access_token,

But my component not get initialised and there is no routing error as well,

Routing :

`<Route path="/logout" component={LogoutComponante} />`

logout component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { LOGOUT } from '../constant/constant'
function LogoutComponante(props){     console.log('in logout');
    // props.logoutmethod();
    // props.history.push("/")
  return <h1>abc</h1>;
} 

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        access_token : state.access_token
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => { 
    return {
        logoutmethod : () => {
            dispatch({ type : LOGOUT })
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LogoutComponante)
```

Routing details:

```
<Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component= {Home} />
                <RouterManager/>
            </Switch>
```

RouterManager component :

```
const RouterManager = (props) => {  
    if(props.access_token){ 
        return (
            <div>
                <Route path="/logout" component={LogoutComponante} />
            </div>

        )
    }else{ 
        return (
            <div>
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Register} />
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

when I visit `/logout` it returns nothing not even `console.log('in logout');`  is working.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried giving `exact` prop to `<Route />`

Comment: @uday yes I have that `<Route exact path="/" component= {Home} />`

Comment: is there any parent route for your `/logout`?

Comment: @Harish I have updated question with routing details

Comment: @ParitoshMahale can you check whether you're getting `access_token` in <RouterManager /> props

Comment: @uday yes I am getting `access_token` in `<RouterManager /> `, On click of logout react redirect me to `/logout` but logout component not get initialised

Comment: did you wrapped `<Switch/>` in `<Router/>` ? And did you used multiple-routers?

Comment: @uday yes I did, my `/register` and `/login` urls are working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your redux component with withRouter. Sometimes you will not see ok changes:

```
import { withRouter, connect } from 'react-redux'
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LogoutComponante))
```